# Kill an automatically delete file script

Tags: bash, terminal, script

Kind of a newbie to bash, sorry.

I wanted to generate a script to enter all directories under current_directory with "bifn*0.2e" in the name and then automatically delete files every minute with "acc" in the name. These are continuously being generated by another process. This is what I have and it seems to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do                                                                                                                  
    find /current_directory/bifn*0.2e* -name '*acc*' -mmin +1 -delete
    sleep 60
done
```

However, after I ran the script ./auto_remove, I did a Ctrl+Z and `bg` to keep it in the background running. I wanted this script to continue removing files even after I exit the terminal. That part works too. But now I cannot kill what it is doing, nor do I see evidence the script is going (except that the acc files are being removed!). I have tried typing `ps fjx` or `jobs.` I have also tried re-running the script with the find line commented out.

So, please help me to stop what it is doing! And, for future use, how can I more elegantly do what I want to do while being able to terminate it when needed?

Comment: Did you invoke `jobs` in the shell that started the script?

Comment: No. I exited that terminal before I knew I what I was doing!

Comment: I would expect `ps fjx` to show `/bin/bash ./auto_remove` among other entries. Does `ps fjx | grep auto_remove` show anything besides the `grep` itself?

Comment: No, I'm on a remote connection so```ps fjx``` shows sshbd: <my_username>@pts/36  and  -bash and \_ ps fjx.  ```ps fjx | grep auto_remove``` shows \_ grep auto_remove

Comment: Also, pstree -pa <my_username> does not give me any evidence this exists: sshbd,13042                                                                    
  ├─bash,13043
  └─bash,13706
      └─pstree,22852 -pa my_username

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the problem with terminating. I had to login to the particular node that was executing that script, to then execute kill. I still am not sure how to avoid this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Half of the script is unnecessary. Remove all checks for time. Just set it to check for name and delete.
Then set it in the crontab on each minute. 
If you want to stop it for some reason, just stop the cron by commenting the execution line and restart the cron